Convert 50fps to 25fps by skipping frames but not changing speed
I have a 50p H264 video which was originally shot normally at 25p, but encoded by some idiot to 50p. So every frame is encoded twice.
Is it possible to copy it by skipping every second frame, and setting the speed to 25p?
I know I could re-encode it at 25p, but I would like to copy the frames without re-encoding.

just drop it in a 25p timeline, will be fine. all NLEs can do that automatically.
